# Block application on mac

Tags: macos, applescript

is there a way to run a simple tell application quit, when a specific application is opened.

For example, if I open spotify, is there away to trigger a script to quit the app.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is a more appropriate forum for sysadmin-type questions. 2. Controlling access to apps and services is what macOS’s mildly misnamed “Parental Controls” (System Events > Users & Groups) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to run a simple tell application quit, when a specific application is opened.

Short Answer: Yes

Longer Answer:

Here are a couple of ways that come to mind...

---

There is a paid *application* called **EventsScripts** that among the many *events* it can react to, one category is **Application Events** which contains, `Application activated`, `Application deactivated`, `Application will launch`, `Application launched` and `Application quit`.

**EventsScripts** works with both **AppleScript** *scripts* and *shell scripts*.

Have a look at [EventScripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html). At the time of this post, it's [$5.99 at the US App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/eventscripts/id525319418?mt=12), but a free demo is downloadable from the developers website.

<sup>**Note:** I am not affiliated with the developer of EventScripts, just a satisfied user of the product.</sup>

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
on run eventArgs
    set thisTrigger to (trigger of eventArgs)
    if thisTrigger is "Application launched" then
        set appName to |applicationName| of eventArgs
        if appName is "Spotify" then
            tell application appName to quit
        end if
    end if
end run
```

---

A free alternative is [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org), although one may find it is not as easy to implement and use as e.g. **EventsScripts**.

Here is an *example* of the *code* used to *watch* for the target *application* has *launched* and then close it using **AppleScript** *code*:

*Example* **Lua** *code*:

```lua
function applicationWatcher(appName, eventType)
    if (eventType == hs.application.watcher.launched) then
        if (appName == "Spotify") then
            hs.applescript('tell application "Spotify" to quit')
        end
    end
end
appWatcher = hs.application.watcher.new(applicationWatcher)
appWatcher:start()
```

This would be placed in the **~/.hammerspoon/init.lua** *file* and with **Hammerspoon** running in the background, when the target *application* is *launched*, it is told to quit via **AppleScript**.

<sup>**Note:** I am not affiliated with the developer of Hammerspoon, just a satisfied user of the product.</sup>